# A problem on orthogonality of functions

Tags: definite-integrals, orthogonality

> Three functions $f_1(t), f_2(t)$ and $f_3(t)$, which are zero outside
>   the interval $[0,T]$, are shown in the figure. Which of the following
>   statements are correct?
>
> - $f_1(t)$ and $f_2(t)$ are orthogonal.
> - $f_1(t)$ and $f_3(t)$ are orthogonal.
> - $f_2(t)$ and $f_3(t)$ are orthogonal.
> - $f_1(t)$ and $f_2(t)$ are orthonormal.

[image]

The solution is :

> Two functions $f(x)$ & $g(x)$ are said to orthogonal if
>   $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx=0$, so we have:
>
> $$\int_{0}^{T}f_2(t)f_3(t)dt=\frac{T}{3}- T +\frac{2T}{3}=0$$

Now my problem is that I can't understand how they did the integral. I have tried to do the integral as:

$$\int_{0}^{T}f_2(t)f_3(t)dt=\int_{0}^{\frac{T}{3}}1\cdot 1dt+\int_{\frac{T}{3}}^{\frac{2T}{3}}(-1)\cdot (-3)dt+\int_{\frac{2T}{3}}^{T}2\cdot 1dt$$

$$\implies \int_{0}^{T}f_2(t)f_3(t)dt= \frac{T}{3}+T+\frac{2T}{3}$$

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct and the textbook's solution is not. Clearly, the function $f_2(t)\cdot f_3(t)$ is an everywhere positive function, so its integral should be greater than $0$.

The two functions that *are* orthogonal are $f_1$ and $f_3$, and your method applied to this pair of functions should show their inner product is $0$.

Comment: Thank you. Also, I think you have a typo in your first `should ` :-)

Comment: @paulplusx Indeed. I fixed it.